# Issue with http authentification on wp-admin access between HTTPS and HTTP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, authentication

First of all, sorry for my bad english :)

I have an issue with wordpress on apache.
My website is fully https.
Certificate is OK.
All website is restricted by http authentification.

On website access (https://www.mywebsite.com/) authentification dialog display (user / password), I put my access login / pass, click OK, and... OK. No issue. I can navigate anywhere without issue, no more authentification dialog, website is always HTTPS.

BUT... in address bar, i put "https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin" and... it's crazy.
When I valid URL, the authentification dialog open again, with domain indication "http://www.mywebsite.com/".
I put again my access / login info and i'm fine redirected to "https://www.mywebsite.com".
New access to wp-admin is now OK, with https, without dialog, without http...

My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
## Default .htaccess file

AuthName "Accès protégé"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

My (partial) wp-config file :

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.mywebsite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.mywebsite.com');
define('WP_CACHE', false);
```

I try with and without this lines :

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

But no change.
I've deactivate all plugins, same issue...
i'm falling completely crazy !
Any help would be very appreciate...

Thanks.
Have a nice day :)